# I want to set the background color of the entire width of the line in EditText

Tags: android, colors, textview, android-edittext, line

I have an EditText box, with multiple lines of text. I want to set some lines to background color blue. I want to set the entire width of the EditText box to blue, not only the background of the text.

Please help!

(I know I can set the background of the text to Blue, by using Span classes, but want to set the blue color accross the entire width of the line - even if the text is present only till the middle of the line)

Answer (score 0):

You can customise your edit text by using the following xml layout

Save the following code as`yourWishName.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

//You can change the color of the edit text here which removes the border line as well
 <item android:state_focused="true" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#F8B334" />
        <corners
            android:radius="12dp" /> 
    </shape>
</item>  
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="0dp"
            android:color="#000000" />
        <corners
            android:radius="12dp" /> 
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

In EditText call the xml `android:background="@drawable/yourWishName"`

Hope this helps

Comment: This has actually set the color and shape of the entire edittext box. I thought this would set the color of selected line. This is not what exactly I wanted. I only want to set the color of ONE line in EditText box to blue. (not the entire edittext box background).

Comment: Oh Sorry i mis understood your question